# Can any of the standard techniques (logistic regression, lda, qda, svm) be used to perform asymmetric classification?

Tags: classification

Suppose I care about mispredicting one class much more than another. 
Is there a way I can communicate this information to the standard classification techniques?

The only way I can think of is adjusting the threshold, but I wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: In discriminant analysis, for example, you can set prior probabilities of belonging to classes as you need. In logistic regression such probability is often called a cut-off value or threshold.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the loss function that is used for fitting the model parameters and evaluating the forecasts. For binary models, there is a large class of loss functions called "proper scoring rules", including e.g. negative likelihood and squared error. These loss functions are sensible from a stat theory perspective since they set the incentive to identify the true model asymptotically. The class contains asymmetric members which you could use in your application. For a good review, see

http://stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~buja/PAPERS/paper-proper-scoring.pdf

Comment: If we have a good idea of the distribution, isn't training with a loss function that matches our real misclassification loss statistically extracting less information from the data? How does one solve this conflict?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I fully get the point. Do you refer to loss functions which basically count the number of correct classifications, such as the one for Manski's maximum score estimator (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304407685900090)? Proper scoring rules are different from this type of misclassification loss - they extract the full amount of information from the data, since they depend on the probabilities $\{p\}_{i=1}^n$ which are assigned to the $n$ outcomes of the binary dependent variable.